# Android Studio not showing files

Tags: android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3h5A.png)

I cannot see the sources file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connection. And wait few minutes

Answer (score 0):

your gradle is not download complete .
after intall android studio u must wait for download automaticaly from internet .but sometime u cant download . then u must change DNS in your pc or use VPN.